# htaccess redirection to another domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am newby in htaccess, please help if you can.
My task is simple, I think.

I have a website, for example **newsite.com**. It was made on wordpress.
And I have old copy of this site, on other domain, for example **oldsite.com**.

When I transfered files from **oldsite** to **newsite** some of pictures didn't transferred to **newsite**, but they still exists on **oldsite**.

Now when pages are loading I checking post thumbnails on **newsite**, and if they don't exists on **newsite**, I am replacing **newsite** url to **oldsite** url.

But is there any ways to not just replace **newsite.com/image.jpg** to **oldsite.com/image.jpg**, but replace **newsite.com/image.jpg**, to, for example **newsite.com/imgs/image.jpg**, and in .htaccess file make rule that if url has **/imgs/** part, it means that need to look for image in **oldsite.com/image.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by below .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

In your new site HTML code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.newurl.com/imgs/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this configuration in the file of virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.org
        DocumentRoot /srv/redireccion
        Redirect permanent / https://example2.org/
</VirtualHost>
```